# Can an arbitrary number of digits from somewhere in the middle of Euler’s constant be calculated?

Tags: numerical-methods, exponential-function

I read this page

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/e.html

But every method to calculate e always begins by generating increasing accuracy from left to right. Is it possible to calculate the 10^9th digit only? Or is it possible to calculate the range of 10 digits from the 10^15th place to the 10^16th? Obviously one could spend a lot of cpu cycles to get to the target digit and only display that one but that is not what I am asking. Rather is it possible to have an expression that generates the digit of interest directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such an algorithm can't be ruled out, but currently there is no known method to generate the $n$th decimal digit of $e$ without generating the preceding digits first.

Remarkably, there *is* an algorithm for generating the $n$th hexadecimal digit of $\pi$ directly. This is the [Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula) discovered by Simon Plouffe in 1995.

Comment: Indeed! It's the pi algorithm that got me thinking about e.